# how to add android linphone to autoconf, automake, aclocal, libtoolize, pkgconfig

Tags: android, android-ndk

1. Download the **Android SDK** with platform-tools and tools updated to latest revision (at least `API 16` is needed), then add both 'tools' and 'platform-tools' folders in your path.
2. Download the Android ndk (>=r8b) from google and add it to your path.
3. Install the autotools: autoconf, automake, aclocal, libtoolize, pkgconfig

Steps 1 and 2 I have completed, but I don't know how do step 3.

Can someone help me fix it in Android Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

For mac os x you can
1) /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

now you can easy install the rest via brew

brew install autoconf

 brew install aclocal

and so on.